# Passing filename from Java to PHP using HTTP URL

Tags: java, php

I want to upload my file from Java using SFTP and upload the file path with PHP script but the problem is I am not getting the path in my PHP script say in a textbox but in my IDE the path is showing

Uploading directly using SFTP is fine but the path of the file is not displaying in my PHP textbox*

**JAVA code**

```
BufferedReader in;
boolean blResult = sftpBean.connect("xx.xxx.xx.x", xx, "xxxx", "xxxx");
if (blResult) {
    System.out.println("Successfull Connection");
    String path="/home/folder/upload/";
    String p="http://xx.xxx.xx.x/upload/";
    blResult = sftpBean.uploadFile(data,result,path);           
    if(blResult) {
        OutputStream os = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        URL url = new URL("http://xx.xxx.xx.x/folder/test.php?test="+p+result); 
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();                          
        in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); 
        String inputLine;         
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
```

**PHP CODE** *test.php*

```
<?php
    $path=$_GET['test'];
    echo "<input type='text' value='$path'>";
?>
```

The expected result would be the path name will display in my php textbox
So far the results display only in my IDE

Comment: IDE result
echo "<input type='text' value='C://Documents/filename.pdf'>"

Comment: What is `result`?

Answer (score 0):

You should [encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding) your query parameters.

```
String testParameterEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(p + result, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
URL url = new URL("http://xx.xxx.xx.x/folder/test.php?test=" + testParameterEncoded);
```